# animated scroll with jquery?

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

hey guys,
i just wrote a little function that filters all anchor links and animates a scroll to the found element.

i just wonder if there is anything i could do better? how would you do that?
i'm actually quite happy with the solution, however maybe you'll find a rather bad-scripted part right away.

http://jsfiddle.net/ueXtq/3/

e.g.
this part looks rather complicated and i wonder if theres a better way to filter the hashtag out of a href attribute?

```
anchor = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
```

thank you for your tipps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 things :

I don't think you need `.each()`.

I don't think you need to `.split()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ueXtq/4/